# what simple extensions can be naturally embedded into Conway's algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, ordinals

John Conway proved in his book, On Numbers and Games (ch6, theorem 49) that the set of all ordinals smaller than $\omega^{\omega^\omega}$ form a field of characteristic 2 that is isomorphic to $\bar{\mathbb{F}_2}$, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_2$.  The arithmetic of this field is described in more detail in Lenstra's note, [On the Algebraic Closure of Two](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/PUBLICATIONS/1977e/art.pdf)  Additionally, there's another good note on this field at [lieven le bruyn's blog, neverendingbooks](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/on2-conways-nim-arithmetics)

In doing so, Conway also proved that the finite numbers that form fields in the same way are of the form $2^{2^k}$. Let $[n]$ denote one of such fields (exempli gratia, $[4]=[2^2] ={0,1,2,3}$, the set of all smaller ordinals.  Hence we have all extensions $[2^{2^n}]$ contained in the algebraic closure.

Is there a choice (and explicit construction) of monic irreducible polynomials $m_n(x)$ of degree $n$ so that the field isomorphism
$$ \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(m_n(x)) \cong [2^n]  $$
is natural for all finite $n=2^k$?

I suppose I need to say what I mean by "natural". Let me try to explain, and please let me know if this makes no sense:  We can always construct such an isomorphim $\phi$, if we choose a root $\mu$ of $m_n(x)$ and a corresponding $\phi(\mu) \in \{3, 4, \ldots, n\}$, then the axioms of fields and isomorphisms will force the other choices (I think).  I want a set of $m_n(x)$'s so that the isomorphism doesn't depend on any arbitrary choices I make.  (I really don't know how to make precise what I mean by natural.  Suffice to say that I'm asking if there is a preferred set of polynomials that make the isomorphism obvious!)

**Update***  Of course, other fields, $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$ for k not a power of two, must also live inside $\omega^{\omega^\omega}$.  As already noted, $[\omega]$ is a quadratic closure. Conway's method is then to take a cubic closure, by noting that $[\omega^3], [\omega^9], \ldots$ are also fields; and then taking a quintic closure through the fields $[\omega^\omega], [\omega^{5 \omega}], \ldots$, et cetera.  Hence a field like $\mathbb{F}_8$ can be embedded into one of the cubic fields, exempli gratia $[\omega^3]$.  Can we describe how $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$ fits into these fields, and can we also find an irreducible polynomial that gives us a natural embedding?

*Perhaps this should be a separate question? Let me know...

Comment: Isomorphic how? One set is naturally *well*-ordered and the other cannot be linearly ordered in coherence with its field structure.

Comment: The field with 8 elements is not an extension field of the field with 4 elements.

Comment: @AsafKaragila field isomorphisms here.  My suspicion from the literature, actually, is that there isn't any preferred field extension, but I wanted to ask the clever folks on here before I run off with that conclusion.

Comment: @Hurkyl a very good point! I'll correct that.

Comment: But the ordinals do not make a good field. Their addition and multiplication is not commutative is hardly invertible. How do you define the addition on the ordinals?

Comment: @AsafKaragila See Conway's book or Lenska's note for that, or even this link: http://www.neverendingbooks.org/index.php/on2-conways-nim-arithmetics.html

the addition is binary arithmetic (for finite numbers) without carrying the extra digit. multiplication is a lot more complicated.

Comment: You may want to add that link to the post.

Comment: +1: Thanks for telling me about this! I didn't know about this construction by Conway (even though I'm relatively familiar with finite NIM-addition). Playing with the multiplication rule a bit quickly leads to the observation that with finite ordinals you only get the fields $F_k=GF(2^{2^k})$ as the intervals $F_k=\{0,1,\ldots,2^{2^k}-1\}$. This family of finite fields has other recursive constructions (trying to reformulate one in a way that helps here). So for example the unique field of 8 elements has the elements 0,1 and then 6 infinite ordinals (that I dare not try and guess yet:-)