# Can we turn $\mathbb N_0$ or $\mathbb Z$ into a field?

Tags: field-theory, integers, natural-numbers

I think that these two sets cannot be turned into fields by re-defining addition or multiplication (or both) but I am not sure how to prove this only from axioms of the field and (if needed) some elementary properties of fields that follow directly from axioms of the field.

My intuition is that $\mathbb N_0$ and $\mathbb Z$ are not "dense enough", as is, for example, $\mathbb Q$, to be able to become fields.

How would you prove that we can(or cannot) turn them into fields?

Comment: If you take any bijection $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$, then pulling back the addition and multiplication from $\mathbb{Q}$, you get a field. However, you cannot expect to preserve other properties, like being an ordered field, with the original order in $\mathbb{Z}$. It will be an ordered field if you also pull back the order from $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure

Comment: A field need not be dense at all. Finite fields are examples. The smallest field $F_{2}$ has cardinality 2!

Comment: $\Bbb{N}_0$ becomes a field when the addition is bitwise XOR and the multiplication is defined by a method due to Conway. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/399718/11619) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/166804/11619) for links to more (you can safely ignore my answer to that question, it is not relevant here).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $X$ be any countably infinite set. Then we have a bijection $\alpha : X \to \mathbb{Q}$. Define $$x\oplus y = \alpha^{-1}(\alpha(x) + \alpha(y)) \quad \quad x\otimes y = \alpha^{-1}(\alpha(x)\alpha(y))$$ where the operations on the right are the natural ones in $\mathbb{Q}$, then you have $(X, \oplus, \otimes)$ a field (isomorphic to the rationals).

Comment: so if $\alpha: \ldots,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots \to  \ldots,-\frac12,-2,-1,0,1,2,\frac12,3,\frac13,4,\ldots$ you get $1\oplus2 = 4$ and  $2 \otimes 2 = 6$

Comment: This answer is exactly the same as the one posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399703/is-it-possible-to-make-integers-a-field/399705#399705)

Answer (score 3):

For prime $p$, $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is a field, under addition and multiplication modulo $p$.